# How is a customers information stored during checkout steps?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I am not a Magento user but I am curious about the platform. I've been looking at a demo store at: http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/

As a customer fills out the various parts of the registration/checkout form, does it write to the database each time a user clicks "continue"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure does!

In Magento there is an object called a Quote. This object is essentially the cart. So when you add a product to your cart, that product is added to the `sales_flat_quote_item` table. There's also a bunch of other quote tables such as `sales_flat_quote_address` `sales_flat_quote_payment`.

It's all done via an Ajax request on that onepage checkout page. After looking more into it it's fairly cool to realize all that goes into just the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Magento saves data in several database tables: customer tables, sales (quote) tables.